# Using AVAudioPlayer in iOS5?

Tags: avaudioplayer

So I'm trying to play a .wave file in iOS5, and I'm getting a warning, which is leading to SIGABRTs and generally not-working code.

```
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Resources/Sounds/01_main_menu_list.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
[_audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
[_audioPlayer play];
```

This is giving me an error "Sending "ViewController *const __strong" to parameter of incompatible type 'id '.

I have literally no idea why, I've followed a half-dozen examples and am coming up empty. I'd love a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was an issue with ARC releasing, I fixed it by adding a @property and @synthesize pair for the AVAudioPlayer in question, and declaring it as strong. It got rid of all of these errors, and played the file with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
NSURL* soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"01_main_menu_list" ofType:@"wav"]]; 
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer play];
```

If not, I think there's something wrong with the wav file. Maybe the encoding?

Comment: That got the file playing, but the warning is still there. Any idea what it means and how I can knock it on the head? It's been drilled into my head that a warning is just an error which hasn't crashed yet :)

Comment: At which line of code do you get the warning, and what exactly does it say?

Comment: the delegate line, and it says exactly what I wrote above.

"Sending "ViewController *const __strong" to parameter of incompatible type 'id '.

Comment: Try to change
audioPlayer.delegate = self;
to 
audioPlayer.delegate = (id)self;

Comment: Also: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364911/handling-app-delegates-and-switching-between-views