# Game Center with iOS 5 SDK - leaderboardDelegate = self not working

Tags: ios5, sdk, automatic-ref-counting, game-center

I am still using iOS 5 SDK and Xcode 4.2 (Snow Leopard). I am adding Game Center to my game and while it passed authentication I get an ARC error whenever I try to show a leaderboard with this code (from Apple):

```
- (void) showLeaderboard: (NSString*) leaderboardID
{
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil)
    {
        **leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;**
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeToday;
        leaderboardController.category = leaderboardID;
        [self presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Passing "ViewController *const__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id <GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate>"
```

Is there any other solution than using iOS 6 SDK on lion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah,

Found a similar problem, using id(self) fixed it;

[Handling app delegates and switching between views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364911/handling-app-delegates-and-switching-between-views)

Should I delete this question>